# PHPStorm autoformating HTML closing html tag

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

When I'm autoformating HTML in PHPStorm, I can't set closing `>` to align with opening `<`

Autoformat does this:

```
<input class="btn btn-highlighted btn-xl"
          type="submit" value="Update stream"
          ng-click="update(); ref.open = false"
          ng-class="{'is-disabled': !sf.$valid}"
          ng-show="folder.id"
          >
```

But I need it to do this:

```
<input class="btn btn-highlighted btn-xl"
          type="submit" value="Update stream"
          ng-click="update(); ref.open = false"
          ng-class="{'is-disabled': !sf.$valid}"
          ng-show="folder.id"
>
```

Is it somehow possible to set? Thanks

Comment: Try to add `/` before `>` and press [Enter] for newline

Comment: Then there would be `/` which is not needed. Also it breaks auto format indent in following code. I have created a feature request, you can vote for it here http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-24172